# Why can't I match to an evaluation?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm trying to generate pascal triangles, using a list of the previous row (tmp) and want to evaluate the size of a list and match to this case like so:

```
(* b is the index pos I'm generating at the moment *)
(* I need a function I can pass into another function, so the case must evaluate at runtime *)

fun b -> match b with
| 0 -> 1
| List.length tmp -> 1
| _ -> (* Ignore this part *)
```

Why doesn't the second line evaluate and match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCaml matches are extremely efficient because the patterns are constants that are known at compile time. To compare against a value computed at run time you can use `if`.

There is also a `when` clause in the `match` that you can use to test the value of an expression after doing an initial match. This is equivalent to an `if` but is sometimes cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`List.length tmp` is not a pattern - this is an expression ;  `match` works only with patterns.
See [patterns](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/patterns.html#pattern)

Comment: how could I convert an expression into a pattern then?

Answer (score 0):

There is no pattern here, only values with conditional expressions to evaluate so use if instructions there are more adapted.

```
    if b = 0 then 1 else
    if b = (List.length tmp) then 1 else
    whatever expression
```